# Using Request.Url.AbsoluteUri to construct a breadcrumb link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Inside my `_layout` view I have added the following link , to  refresh the current page as part my breadcrumb bar:

```
<a href="@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri"> @(aoutput == "Index" ? "Home" : aoutput) </a>
```

The above is working well on my development environment , but I am not sure If using the `Request.Url.AbsoulteUri` is the correct way to reference the current page URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AbsoluteUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) includes the [scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) (such as `http`), the host, the port, the path, query string data and the [fragment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.fragment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As far as I know the fragment will not be included in the current URL because it is not sent with the request (that is, it's handled by the browser client-side).

This should be fine to use and is unlikely to cause you issues. Just be aware that query string data is included, which means that if you had a (poorly-designed) data manipulation system such as `/Users/Index?action=deleteMostRecentUser` then the user might accidently delete users because the URI would include the `action`.

Alternatives are

- [Absolute Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `/Home/Index`
- [Path & Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `/Home/Index?query=keyword`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but do u mean by  (poorly-designed) data manipulation system that i am deleting a record using a Get request instead of Post,,which is not the case in my system? all the Add,Edit and delte inside my system are being issued using Post requests, so the breadcrumb link will only send Get requests.. i am missing any thing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as you mentioned.
Better way you make a separate partial view to implement breadcrumb.
And pass wanted model from Controller side. (Or in ViewBag)

The main benefit is you'll get is better control over Logic also flexible for future changes.
Hope helps.